# Transfer info in html5 form into text file

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm looking to create a form for collecting the name and email from people and gathering them in a txt document in an html5 webpage.  What is the best way to do this?

Here is what I have so far:

[Screenshot of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvwMz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be a newbie so I'm gonna propose you a simple solution. You have to implement a server which a route that retrieve your datas and put them into your .txt file.

You can tried to use an Apache server and use PHP. You will find a lot of tutorials on the web.